# Is it okay to extend some class and use it in build()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that presents an error to a user. I want to have it in two variations:

- the first would be a page element to show the error right in the view, replacing some portion of content
- the second would be presented to a user as a dialog window.

For the second one I want to tweak the layout a little bit and use `Dialog` as a wrapped. So I created a separate widget, who extends my current one so I can skip adding duplicate fields in class.

```dart
class ConnectionErrorDialog extends ConnectionErrorWidget {
  ConnectionErrorDialog(
      {required String errorText,
      required VoidCallback mainButtonOnTap,
      String mainButtonText = 'Понятно'})
      : super(
            errorText: errorText,
            mainButtonText: mainButtonText,
            mainButtonOnTap: mainButtonOnTap);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
        elevation: 24.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ConnectionErrorWidget(
            errorText: errorText,
            mainButtonOnTap: mainButtonOnTap,
            mainButtonText: mainButtonText,
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ConnectionErrorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ConnectionErrorWidget({
    required this.errorText,
    required this.mainButtonOnTap,
    this.mainButtonText = 'Попробовать снова',
  });

  final String errorText;

  final String mainButtonText;

  final VoidCallback mainButtonOnTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UserErrorWidget(
        errorText: errorText,
        mainButtonText: mainButtonText,
        mainButtonOnTap: mainButtonOnTap,
        showAsDialog: false);
  }
}
```

I want to understand, is it even okay to extend some class and use it in build()? Maybe there's other, better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend widgets like that, but the only benefit is omitting fields duplication. But it looks like you can do something like that:

```
class ConnectionErrorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConnectionErrorWidget({
    @required this.errorText,
    @required this.mainButtonOnTap,
    this.mainButtonText,
    this.showAsDialog = false,
  });

  final bool showAsDialog;
  final String errorText;
  final String mainButtonText;
  final VoidCallback mainButtonOnTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (showAsDialog) {
      return Dialog(
          elevation: 24.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: _buildUserError(),
          ));
    }
    return _buildUserError();
  }

  Widget _buildUserError() {
    return UserErrorWidget(
        errorText: errorText,
        mainButtonText: mainButtonText ?? (showAsDialog ? 'Попробовать снова' : 'Понятно'),
        mainButtonOnTap: mainButtonOnTap,
        showAsDialog: showAsDialog);
  }
}
```

In that case, besides omitting fields duplication, your benefit is constructor arguments omitting.
I think that there is not much difference between these variants and you can use any variant you like more.